# PyQGIS export raster layer with resolution instead of size

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

[image: QGIS prompt window]

```
                file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(self.mypath + f'/{self.Name}_2x2DEM.tif')
                pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
                provider = DEMlayer.dataProvider()
                pipe.set(provider.clone())
                file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, 241, 213, DEMlayer.extent(), DEMlayer.crs(),)
```

For this code here, I hard coded it with 241 in Column, 213 in Rows in order to get 2x2 resolution.

Main problem:
When I try to reuse the code with another GeoTiff image with different size, the resolution is not correct.

Is there anyway to set the horizontal to 2 and vertical to 2 instead of using rows/column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raster writer https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterFileWriterTask.html requires the number of columns and rows as input. For achieving the desired resolution you must calculate the values first.

- Take the layer extent
- Take MinX, MaxX, MinY, MaxX from the extent
- Divide the net width and height by resolution
- Thats it

Comment: Is there anything with the net width and height with any function?

Comment: Sure, max - min.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can answer your question.

```
from qgis.core import (
  QgsRasterFileWriter,
  QgsRasterPipe
)
rlayer=iface.activeLayer()
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('myRaster.tif')
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
provider = rlayer.dataProvider()
pipe.set(rlayer.dataProvider().clone())
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, rlayer.width(), rlayer.height(), rlayer.extent(), rlayer.crs(),)
```

If you still have some questions, I'm glad to receive your message!